# Is there a closed form expansion for $(2^k + 1)^{k+1}$?

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

Is there a way to express $(2^k + 1)^{k+1}$ expanded...

The first few values for $k+1=2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$ are:

$
k+1=2: 1+2^{2 k}+2^{1+k}
$
$
k+1=3: 1+3\ 2^k+3\ 2^{2 k}+2^{3 k}
$
$
k+1=4: 1+2^{4 k}+2^{2+k}+3\ 2^{1+2 k}+2^{2+3 k}
$
$
k+1=5: 1+5\ 2^k+5\ 2^{4 k}+2^{5 k}+5\ 2^{1+2 k}+5\ 2^{1+3 k}
$
$
k+1=6: 1+15\ 2^{2 k}+15\ 2^{4 k}+2^{6 k}+3\ 2^{1+k}+5\ 2^{2+3 k}+3\ 2^{1+5 k}
$
$
k+1=7: 1+7\ 2^k+21\ 2^{2 k}+35\ 2^{3 k}+35\ 2^{4 k}+21\ 2^{5 k}+7\ 2^{6 k}+2^{7 k}
$

Comment: Binomial theorem?

Comment: $(2^k+1)^{k+1}$ is pretty "closed form" already. An expansion involving $\sum$ would not be "closed form".

Comment: $(2^k+1)^{k+1}$ seems to be a pretty good one.

Comment: The size of the value is $O(1)^{k^2}$, so you'll never be able to compute it in polytime.  At best you can ask for certain digits in polytime.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem,
$$(2^k+1)^{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}2^{ik}$$

Take Pascal's triangle and multiply each term in a row by increasing powers of $2^k$.

If you really want to group with the powers of 2 contained in the coefficients, you can use the divisibility criterion of Kummer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties

Let $C(m, n)$ be the number of carries when performing the binary addition of $m$ and $n$. You can rewrite as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\frac{\binom{k+1}{i}}{2^{C(i, k+1-i)}}2^{ik+C(i, k+1-i)},$$
such that the coefficients are odd.

For example, for $k+1=4$:

$000_b+100_b\rightarrow$ no carry, $001_b+011_b\rightarrow 2$ carries, $010_b+010_b\rightarrow 1$ carry...

$$\begin{align}1.2^0+ 4.2^3 + 6.2^6+ 4.2^9+ 1.2^{12}&=\frac1{2^0}.2^{0+0}+\frac4{2^2}.2^{3+2}+\frac6{2^1}.2^{6+1}+\frac4{2^2}.2^{9+2}+\frac1{2^0}.2^{12+0}\\&=1+2^5+3.2^7+2^{11}+2^{12}\end{align}$$

Comment: Would there then be an easy way to convert the carry formula to its canonical base-2 representation: $\sum b_i 2^i$... This would allow for the computation of the $k$-th row and $n$-th element of the Pascal triangle...

Comment: I just linked the question to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810633/efficient-way-to-compute-the-binomial-using-2k1k1... Since Yves' answer seems to solve this question...

Comment: Then it would be nice to mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: If the goal is to easily compute Pascal's triangle, I am afraid this is a step back. Finding the largest power in the coefficients is not helpful, on the opposite, and the standard binomial formula is still there. This approach makes sense if you have a fast multiplier of arbitrarily large binary numbers.